# Piping the output to cat

Tags: c, linux, cat

I have the following prog written:

```
int main() 
{
printf("one\n");
write(1, "two\n", 4);
return 0;
}
```

And then i give the command 
./a.out | cat 
at the terminal to which the output comes to be
two
one 
instead of 
one
two
Why???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `printf`'s output will get buffered by the `libc`, `write`'s output will not get buffered. It's a *direct*, unbuffered operation on a *file* (stdout)

Read [this](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/):

> if stdout is a terminal then buffering is automatically set to line buffered, else it is set to buffered

So, you are actually piping to `cat` - that's why buffering is enabled (try without `cat` to see)

To turn off the buffering issue the `stdbuf` command:

```
stdbuf -o0 ./a.out  | cat
```

By the way, that's a really good question to ask for someone who isn't an every day C hacker! Simple and descriptive!

Answer (score 4):

As hek2mgl pointed out, it's because of buffering.  You can put `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` if you want to force things.